# How do I clear all parameters of a request in Restsharp?

Tags: c#, restsharp

Before the newest versions, I simply used request.Parameters.clear()

But this method seems to have disappear on the newest versions.

Is there a way to clear all parameters ?

I tried
`

```
foreach (Parameter p in request.Parameters)
{
request.Parameters.RemoveParameter(p.Name);
}
```

`

but it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you just set request.Parameters = null?

Comment: request.Parameters is a readonly property.

Comment: What's the purpose of cleaning the parameters collection? Can't you avoid adding parameters that aren't needed in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

If you retrieve the list of your parameters, then remove each parameter using this new list, everything shall be removed. See code below:

```
var list = request.Parameters.ToList();

foreach (var elem in list)
{
     request.RemoveParameter(elem);
}
```